# EntityException ao conectar-se com banco de dados remoto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Ao conectar-se com o banco local, a aplicação funciona 100%. Contudo, quando tento conectar-me com o sql server remotamente (em um server da redehost), a aplicação levanta a seguinte exception:

Segue abaixo erro e a connectionstring.

> add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data  Source=HOST;
>   Initial Catalog=bancodados;Integrated  Security=True; persist security
>   info=False;User ID=ID;  Password=SENHA;"
>   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
>
> {"O caminho da rede não foi encontrado"}

Existe alguma configuração no db ou na aplicação que impossibilite esta conexão?

Comment: Você consegue se conectar a este servidor pelo SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Uma vez comigo aconteceu, que no lugar do HOST eu estava passando o IP e não ia nem com reza braba. Aí passei assim: Nome_Servidor\Nome_Instância e consegui me conectar. Não sei se você já tentou.

Answer (score 1):

Para qualquer conexão remota com o SQL você precisa passar o `IP\Nome_da_instancia`. Pode ser também o `Nome_Servidor\Nome_da_instancia`, porém aí você depende de que a parte de resolução de nomes esteja funcionando corretamente. Além disso, verifique se você consegue se conectar pelo SQL Server Management Studio. Existem configurações a serem feitas no host para permitir conexões remotas.